# How to assign a same value as the argument to a vector of functions in R?

Tags: r, apply

I have this code in R:

```
RdWh <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white"))
GrWh <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "white"))
BlWh <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white"))
color.gradient.3 <- c(RdWh, GrWh, BlWh)
```

Then I want to get a vector

```
c(RdWh(10), GrWh(10), BlWh(10))
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Just `lapply(color.gradient.3,function(x) x(10))` (you might want to `unlist` the result).

Comment: thank you, could you write it into answer, and output the result as a vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid writing a bunch of calls to `colorRampPalette()`, you could put your color vectors into a list, `color`, and run that list through `sapply()`, where we can also call `n = 10` on each run at the same time.  Then wrap with `c()` to get a vector result, as desired.

```
color <- list(RdWh = c("red", "white"), GrWh = c("green", "white"), BlWh = c("blue", "white"))
c(sapply(color, function(x) colorRampPalette(x)(10)))
```

Comment: how can I get a vector?

Comment: @lanselibai - It is a vector now

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
color.gradient.3 <- function(n){
  RdWh <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white"))
  GrWh <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "white"))
  BlWh <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white"))
  c(RdWh(n), GrWh(n), BlWh(n))
}

color.gradient.3(10)
```

or

```
color.gradient.3 <- function(n){
  RdWh <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white"))
  GrWh <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "white"))
  BlWh <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white"))
  c(RdWh(n/3), GrWh(n/3), BlWh(n/3))
}

color.gradient.3(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this...

```
cg3 <- function(n) sapply(color.gradient.3, function(x) x(n))

cg3(10)
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
 [1,] "#FF0000" "#00FF00" "#0000FF"
 [2,] "#FF1C1C" "#1CFF1C" "#1C1CFF"
 [3,] "#FF3838" "#38FF38" "#3838FF"
 [4,] "#FF5555" "#55FF55" "#5555FF"
 [5,] "#FF7171" "#71FF71" "#7171FF"
 [6,] "#FF8D8D" "#8DFF8D" "#8D8DFF"
 [7,] "#FFAAAA" "#AAFFAA" "#AAAAFF"
 [8,] "#FFC6C6" "#C6FFC6" "#C6C6FF"
 [9,] "#FFE2E2" "#E2FFE2" "#E2E2FF"
[10,] "#FFFFFF" "#FFFFFF" "#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: how can I get a vector?

Comment: It is a matrix, so can be treated as a vector (columnwise) - e.g. `cg3(10)[15]`
is the same as `cg3(10)[5,2]` or `"#71FF71"`